# Primer design using ecoPrimers - error when using ecofind command

Tags: bioinformatics

I've been following a tutorial sent to me by Frederic Boyer as a first time user of ecoPrimers and run into trouble when I run the the following command and I'm not sure how to solve it:

```
./ecofind -d ecodb/chloroGenus Tracheophyta 

# 
#  opening ecodb/chloroGenus_001 database
Error 1 in file ecoIOUtils.c line 101 : Cannot open file
Abort trap: 6
```

This command is supposed to retrieve taxonomic information from a database that I created in previous command lines.

I'm very new to bioinformatics so very sorry if this is a really silly question but I can't seem to find anything helpful on the internet.

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks, 
Elle.

Comment: With error messages like this, the most likely reason is that you mistyped the file path or are in the wrong directory. Make sure that the file `ecodb/chloroGenus_001` exists, and is located below the current path.

Comment: Thanks Kondrad, that solved my problem! I had to move the executive files into my usr/local/bin folder and then I could access them

Comment: I experienced the same error when trying to run an ecoPCR command. Thank you @KonradRudolph, indeed, I mistyped the file path.